# How to create local proxy server accessible to machines on LAN

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, ssh-tunnel

My requirement is ...
Route "all" the traffic from locally connected machine A to pass through machine B, as if the traffic originally got generated from machine B.

Reason..

Machine B has access to some remote resources via a private VPN connection e.g. database servers, hosted repositories etc.

The problem..

Only one person can use the remote resources at a time makes it frustrating if 2 or 3 guys need to access the remote resources.

Bottom line...
i need a way so all my users could somehow route their network traffic through that machine B, so all can work at the same time with the remote resources that are only available when the private VPN is connected on machine B.

I have tried ssh tunneling with no significant results as every application needs to be configured to use socks to route the traffic from that application to the proxy server. i need something global!

Any Help?

Update 1:

I have managed to make it work by 
1- creating a sshd server on machine B and did ssh from machine A in to B.
2- set the socks5 proxy on machine A.

but machine A is only routing successfully if machine A is on ubuntu, whereas when using machine A with windows 10, doesn't route the traffic to the machine B.

Any help?

Update 2:

Even on ubuntu it seems that only traffic for port 80 is being forwarded... Nothing else is working..

Need help!

Answer (score 1):

B is capable of routing? Then add a static route for the VPN connected network using B as gateway in the routing table of the default gateway of your LAN (or of all end hosts).

Comment: A little explanation would be great, i am not a pro network guy. After connecting to VPN, if i am gonna set the new IP of machine B, given by VPN as the gateway of other computers in network, will they be able to ping that "new IP" on machine B? What makes B capable of routing?

Comment: @perfect duffer: Broad question broad answer. Give us more details so we can give more detailed advise. What OS is B running (As the OS makes the machine capable of routing.)? What type of VPN is that? Whats your default gateway the hosts use running (OS or if some specialized equipment producer ant type, e.g. Cisco 111 (fictional, I don't know if that actually exists))? The default gateway is the router that gets all packets that another computer has no suitable route to the destination (i.e. doesn't know how to reach it.), can usually be seen in the adapter settings (`ipconfig`, `ifconfig`).

Comment: bit .. Machine is running windows 10.. All the machines are on LAN over wifi and are normal machines used for software development. Its a private VPN provided by the company we are working for and we connect it through a vpn client named network connect. Default Gateway is the normal OS gateway and i dont want to change the gateway globally, the setup is only for specific users working from behind the VPN. Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: @perfext duffer: OK Windows 10 then... I was hoping for something lesstrouble some regarding this, like some BSD or Linux. Before I start to tell you in detail what can be done and what obstacles lie ahead: Is there any chance to replace B with a BSD, Linux or at least some server version of Windows? That would make it easier. You might also talk to your customer which VPN technology they are exactly using, that might help to answer the question if it's possible to connect to it without that Windows VPN client software.

Comment: As i said that they all are development machines and are configured with all the tools necessary for development including windows, so the setup can not be changed. Further, how about somehow making machine B act like a proxy server so all the traffic from machine A routes through B? Or creating a local vpn server on machine B and machine a connects to the local vpn? not sure if two vpns will share the network traffic.

Comment: Think about an additional machine. The OP gave me the impression that you already tried a sort of proxy but gave up because there are to many hosts and services in the remote net? What about installing the VPN client on the other machines? If that VPN allows multiple connections. May have its downsides too, as a machine connected to the VPN might not be able to reach the LAN anymore (some VPN clients might do that) or the whole internet traffic going through the VPN (which usually won't make it faster and may arise some privacy concerns) but maybe worth a try.

Comment: Ok, i sort of have solved it, made machine B a proxy server through ssh tunneling... Accessing it with socks proxy from machine A. Things are sort of working fine.. Let me do some testing, will get back with the results and detailed answer.